# Cannot perform generalized eigenvalue problem with positive definitive symmetrical matricies with OjAlgo - What wrong am I doing?

Tags: java, eigenvalue, eigenvector, ojalgo

Trying to solve generalized eigenvalues on the form:

```
A*V = B*V*D
```

By using OjAlgo. According to the documentation [here](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node54.html) `A` and `B` bust be real symmetric or complex Hermitian and B is positive definite. In this case, both `A` and `B` are symmetrical and positive definitive.

OjAlgo is the only Java math library that can solve generalized eigenvalue problems. So this must work. But why does my output says that I can't solve it?

```
public class Eig {

    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Eig.class);

    // A*V = B*D*V - Find D and V - Will not work for current OjAlgo version
    static public void eig(MatrixStore<Double> Sb, MatrixStore<Double> Sw, Primitive64Store D, Primitive64Store V, long dim) {

        // Create eigA and eigB from symmetrical positive definitive A and B
        Primitive64Matrix eigA = Primitive64Matrix.FACTORY.rows(Sb.toRawCopy2D());
        Primitive64Matrix eigB = Primitive64Matrix.FACTORY.rows(Sw.toRawCopy2D());

        System.out.println("Check if eigA and eigB are symmetrical:");
        System.out.println(eigA.isSymmetric());
        System.out.println(eigB.isSymmetric());

        System.out.println("Check if eigA and eigB are positive definitive:");
        Primitive64Matrix z = Primitive64Matrix.FACTORY.makeFilled(dim, 1, new Weibull(5, 2));
        System.out.println("Positive definitive:");
        System.out.println(z.transpose().multiply(eigA).multiply(z).get(0, 0)); // z^T*eigA*z
        System.out.println(z.transpose().multiply(eigB).multiply(z).get(0, 0)); // z^T*eigB*z

        // Perform [A][V] = [B][V][D]
        Eigenvalue.Generalised<Double> eig = Eigenvalue.PRIMITIVE.makeGeneralised(eigA, Generalisation.A_B);
        boolean success = eig.computeValuesOnly(eigA, eigB);
        if (success == false)
            logger.error("Could not perform eigenvalue decomposition!");


        System.out.println("Check if D and V are null");
        System.out.println(eig.getD() == null);
        System.out.println(eig.getV() == null);

        // Copy over to D, V
        D.fillColumn(0, eig.getD().sliceDiagonal());
        double[][] eigV = eig.getV().toRawCopy2D();
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            V.fillRow(i, Access1D.wrap(eigV[i]));
        }

        // Sort eigenvalues and eigenvectors descending by eigenvalue
        if(eig.isOrdered() == false)
            Sort.sortdescended(V, D, dim); 

    }
}
```

What have I missed?

```
Check if eigA and eigB are symmetrical:
true
true
Check if eigA and eigB are positive definitive:
Positive definitive:
1.0766814686417156E10
1.1248634208301022E9
Check if D and V are null:
true
true
```

**Update 1:**

The procedure will work If both `A` and `B` have only positive real values.

```
        Primitive64Store mtrxA = Primitive64Store.FACTORY.makeSPD((int) dim);
        Primitive64Matrix eigA = Primitive64Matrix.FACTORY.rows(mtrxA.toRawCopy2D());
        Primitive64Store mtrxB = Primitive64Store.FACTORY.makeSPD((int) dim);
        Primitive64Matrix eigB = Primitive64Matrix.FACTORY.rows(mtrxB.toRawCopy2D());

        PrintMatrix.printMatrix(eigB);

        /*
         * There are several generalisations. 3 are supported by ojAlgo, specified by the enum:
         * Eigenvalue.Generalisation This factory method returns the most common alternative.
         */
        Eigenvalue.Generalised<Double> generalisedEvD = Eigenvalue.PRIMITIVE.makeGeneralised(eigA);
        // Generalisation: [A][V] = [B][V][D]

        // Use 2-args alternative

        generalisedEvD.decompose(eigA, eigB);

        System.out.println("Check if D and V are null");
        System.out.println(generalisedEvD.getD() == null); // false
        System.out.println(generalisedEvD.getV() == null); // false
```

**Update 2:**

I did run a test with GNU Octave at it seems that all eigenvalues are positive and the rest are negative, but extreamly close to zero.

Here is an output. It's the same data I have used in GNU Octave as in OjAlgo. I think that e-18 can count as a zero.

I build my `A` and `B` as they should be symmetrical and positive definitive. Is this caused by floating values?

```
   2.7414e+04
   9.4155e+03
   4.1295e+03
   3.1429e+03
  -8.4338e-16
  -1.6409e-15
          Inf
          Inf
          Inf
          Inf
          Inf
          Inf
          Inf
          Inf
          Inf
          Inf
   3.4910e-15
  -8.7739e-16
  -3.1775e-15
  -2.8213e-18
  -5.0274e-16
   1.7329e-18
  -1.1330e-15
   3.1024e-18
   2.3226e-15
  -1.6151e-16
  -6.8453e-16
   1.6111e-17
  -1.7850e-18
  -1.3411e-18
  -2.3916e-18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code example you call:

```
eig.computeValuesOnly(eigA, eigB);
```

which will give you the eigenvalues only (no vectors or matrices). In the second example you instead call the usual:

```
generalisedEvD.decompose(eigA, eigB);
```

Comment: Thanks. But the error remains. Still null `getD()` and null `getV()` with `decompose`. As you see. There are 14 positive eigenvalues. That's because I have data of 14 different images. So the very low and close-to-zero eigenvalues can be interpreted as zeros in my opinion because I'm not going to use them in my calculation. That's the reason why I open a question about descended eigenvalues. I'm only going to pick the amout of eigenvalues as the amout of pictures. Which are the only positive, counted from the top.

Comment: So to summarize, the negative smal eigenvalues are garbage values. They would not even affect my computations if I include them. May be overfitting some times.

Comment: I upload the matrices/data I'm using with GNU Octave. https://easyupload.io/4c23se The files name is`data` and it's a text file. It includes `Sb` and `Sw` where being computed as `[V, D] = eig(Sb, Sw)`

Comment: Hi Anders! I solved this issue by adding reguluarization onto B with `B = B + lambda*I`. Now it's working. Perhaps this can be something for OjAlgo. Automatic regularization? I think here is special cases when it's needed.